# When stopping the Media Player there is an error with the seek bar

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

// method for stopping the media player

```
    private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

//playCycle method for seekbar and time

```
    public void playCycle(){
    mSeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playCycle();
                long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

                crnt.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
                ttl.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

    }
}
```

Logcat- lines 203,209 refers to mSeekBar.setProgress and to playCycle().

08-13 17:57:16.215 21164-21164/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder, PID: 21164
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder.RecordsActivity.playCycle(RecordsActivity.java:203)
                                                                                             at com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder.RecordsActivity$6.run(RecordsActivity.java:209)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Your Mediaplayer object is null, add your complete code or check null before use that variable.

Comment: You have to review the entire code of `playCycle()` method. Not only you have to check if `mp != null` before use it, but you must `synchronize` any access on object `mp`.

Comment: What do you mean by synchronize?